# how to change workspace in exercism in pc driver?

Tags: workspace

I tried this :

```
exercism configure —token="your token" —workspace ="path to some where other than C drive"
```

but it did not work
in `exercism` the tracks download in the C drive and I didn't like to go there and change it to other drive and other folder? how can I do that change?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find my answer my problem is about code that i type in the cmd I sould type is to work correct

```
exercism configure --token=(your token get from site) -w (some location)
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried this and it worked for me

```
exercism configure --workspace="path where you want to put exercism folder" (eg "~/Documents/rustcode")
```

I had already configured my token before.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna go through the process and understand exercism cli, Follow through,

On cmd

```
exercism --help
```

which will show you all available commands

```
exercism configure
```

which will show you the current configuration

```
exercism configure --workspace=C:/path/to/the/dir
```

which will change your current working directory.

**Note: Please change "\" to "/" otherwise it will not work.**